# Logical "and" character in TeX (⋀)

Tags: symbols, syntax

I'm trying to write a logical syllogism in the form of ((a -> b) & (c -> a)) -> (c -> b). But I don't know how to write Logical **And** character. It's something like caret character (^), but not as a superscript.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
$((a\implies b) \land (c\implies a)) \implies (c \implies b)$
```

`\land` and `\wedge` are synonymous.

Comment: I would recommend going with `\land` since it's the semantic variant and because of the command's similarity to other logical connectives such as `\lor` and `\lnot`.

Comment: I second @NN, IMHO this is the natural choice.

Comment: I don't have `\implies` just used`\rightarrow`

Answer (score 31):

In case you don't like the default `\wedge` symbol, you can try the one provided by the `mathabx` package:

[image: MathABX]

**EDIT:** Oh the shame, not even an example? Based on egreg's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
% from egreg's solution
$((a \implies b) \land (c \implies a))  (c \implies  b)$
\end{document}
```

Note that the use of `mathabx` is just an aesthetic choice. Since you are writing logic, egreg's approach is the way to go, since it's more semantic.

Comment: What is mathabax @Paulo?

Comment: @Saeed: It's a package `=)`. You can load it by putting `\usepackage{mathabx}` in your document preamble. I never used myself, but I found it in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), page 23. You can find other alternative symbols in there.

Answer (score 11):

use `$\wedge$` or `$\bigwedge$`